# how to add custem attribute properties for a ldap user in apache ds server

Tags: active-directory, ldap, apacheds

i am trying to learn about LDAP and basic server creation and authenticating from client completed.

now i want add custom attribute properties for an user like cn,uid or sn i want to add networkGrp, srcIp,DestIp like that but if i add apache ds studio ignoring.

[image]

for this user i want to add some custom properties
[image]

but i ldap rejecting these changes

please help me how to add custom attribute properties

Answer (score 0):

In order to do what you want, you would have to extend the InetOrgPerson class.  Just as InetOrgPerson extends organizationalPerson.  See rfc2798.

Alternatively, for the very lazy....  I do not recommend this, but I have done it.  I just find an attribute that I am not using in InetOrgPerson (like carLicense), and use that instead for my own purposes.  Very quick and dirty.